# How to comment in jupyter lab with mac on brave

Tags: macos, comments, jupyter-lab, french, brave

I am facing some issues with commenting a block of lines in jupyterlab, and it is getting so annoying. I have a Mac with a french keyboard layout AZERTY. I also use Brave as browser.

I already tried a lot of shortcuts found on forums but none of them were useful for me. Of course I already tried Cmd + / and didn't work.

Please do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution, but I had to remap my keyboard and set '***/*** ' apart without having to shift to get it. To remap the keyboard I used Ukelele as an app by following this tutorial:

[Tutorial of remapping keyboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ky6zzzAkqHc)

Once done I used Ctrl + / to comment a block in jupyterlab (you may try cmd + / otherwise)